# Problema con configuration de SMTP y PHMailer

Tags: php

Se que hay muchos post sobre este problema en especifico pero no los entiendo. El problema que me arrojo fue este:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'PHPMailer/Exception.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php71/pear') in
>   /home/customer/www/delivery-maxipizza.com/public_html/send.php on line
>   27

Les agradecería si pudieran orientarme. He visto en algunos lados que hay que descargar unos archivos y los tengo descargados en la carpeta donde están el html y php, pero la cuestión es que ¿la ubicación cuando los subo al hosting no cambiaría? ¿Qué es el require PHPMailer? ¿Qué me pide? Esa esta dentro de la carpeta junto con los archivos de html.

PHP MAIL

```
<?php 

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); echo "</pre>"; 


echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;



     //asignando data from $_POST array a variables 
    if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

      //Obtenemos valores input formulario
      $Nombre       = $_POST['Name'];
      $Correo        = $_POST['Correo']; 
      $Delivery     = $_POST['Direccion'];
      $Method       = $_POST['Pago'];
      $TOTAL        = $_POST['tot'];
      $Contenido= "Nombre : "  . $Nombre . "\nCorreo : " . $Correo . "\nDireccion : " . $Delivery . "\nMetodo De Pago : " . $Method . "\nTOTAL : " . $TOTAL . "\nPedido del usuario: " . $Select ;
    }
    $Select = implode(' | ', $_POST['modulo']); 
    // construyendo el asunto del email// 


// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
// These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';




// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp1.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'tucorreo';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'clave';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` also accepted
    $mail->Port       = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', $Nombre);
     // Add a recipient
    $mail->addAddress('donde llega el correo');               // Name is optional


    // Attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
    $mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name

    // Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'PEDIDO A MAXIPIZZA';
    $mail->Body    =  $Contenido;


    $mail->send();

     if ($mail == true){
         echo '<script> 
                alert("TU PEDIDO SE REALIZO CON EXITO");
                windows.history.go(-1);
               </script>';

        } 

} catch (Exception $e) { 
         echo 'hubo algun error al enviar su pedido: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
     }



?>
```

Comment: Podrías enseñar el código? Cómo haces los requires?

Comment: Listo ya resumi

Comment: Prueba con estas dos cosas: Mueve arriba del todo las dos instrucciones `use ...` y también cambia los `require` para añadirle `./` al inicio de cada ruta (cambia los tres requires) Por ejemplo, tras cambiar el primer require se leería así: `require './PHPMailer/Exception.php';`

Comment: ahora me sale este error  `2020-02-19 04:12:19 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0) 2020-02-19 04:12:19 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting hubo algun error al enviar su pedido: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

Answer (score 0):

de antemano te digo que si tienes pensado utilizar PHPMailer en un hosting como goDaddy, no te va a funcionar, ya que ahi lo tienen bloqueado, te recomiendo que investigues si al hosting que quieres registrarte permite el uso de PHPMailer. Respondiendo a tu duda, puedes poner la carpeta con los archivos `exception.php`,`PHPMailer.php` y `SMTP.php` en la de public html tal cual. Te recomiendo infinityfree.net ya que ahi lo puedes usar sin ningun problema.

Comment: gracias por la información compañero pero donde alojo mi sitio es en Siteground, con respecto a lo de la carpeta  ya están en la misma ubicación donde el html

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer] para que conozcas como realizar respuestas en el sitio, saludos.